# How to create seat arrangement SSRS report

Tags: .net, visual-studio, report, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I want to create unsold seat SSRS report. I have vertically align report like
[image: Current layout]

But I want following design
[image: Desired layout]

Data return from stored procedure is
[image: SP return]

How to implement this design in SSRS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you cannot change your stored proc (if you can then you can do this work in there directly).

```
DECLARE @RowWidth int = 5
CREATE TABLE #t (GroupLabel CHAR(1), SeatLabel int)

INSERT INTO #t EXEC myStoredProc

SELECT 
        GroupLabel, SeatLabel
        , CEILING((SeatLabel -1) / @RowWidth)  AS SeatRow
        , (SeatLabel - 1) % @RowWidth as colGrp
    FROM #t
```

If your stored proc produced 20 results, A 1-10 and B-10 then the results would be as follows.
[image]

Add a mtrix control and then group by GroupLabel and SeatRow as row groups and then add a column group on colGrp.

The final report design looks something like this (the expression is simply GroupLabel and SeatLabel concatenated. ( `=Fields!GroupLabel.Value & Fields!SeatLabel.Value`)

[image]

And the final output looks like this

[image]

It's not 100% but with a bit of formatting it should be close enough.

Comment: Matrix layout didn't work for me so I use table layout and it gives the desired layout. Your logic is really helpful.